# Is there an email sending software that I can change the from address based on something?

Tags: flutter, email

I'm making a flutter app, and I need to change the from address based on a variable's value. Is there any good software that supports multiple from addresses? I have previously used Firebase Trigger Email.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good plugin on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) that lets me send emails from SMTP based on data from firebase. It's called [smtpman](https://pub.dev/packages/smtpman) and I used it in a function to send a simple email from a contact form:

```
  sendContactEmail() async {
    SmtpMan smtpman = SmtpMan();
    smtpman.setServer(
      host: "mail.server.com",
      username: "no-reply@mycompany.com",
      password: "**********",
      authentication: true,
      port: Port.to_465,
      secure: Secure.auto,
    );

    smtpman.receipt(
      senderName: "My Company",
      sendToEmail: "contact@mycompany.com",
      subject: "My Company Contact Form",
      body: '''
      <p>Contact Information:</p>
      <table style="width: 97%; margin-left: calc(3%);">
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td style="width: 50.0000%;"><br>Full Name<br><br></td>
                  <td style="width: 50.0000%;">NAME</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td style="width: 50.0000%;"><br>Company<br><br></td>
                  <td style="width: 50.0000%;">COMPANY</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td style="width: 50.0000%;"><br>Email<br><br></td>
                  <td style="width: 50.0000%;">EMAIL</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td style="width: 50.0000%;"><br>Phone<br><br></td>
                  <td style="width: 50.0000%;">PHONE</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td style="width: 50.0000%;"><br>Selected Plan<br><br></td>
                  <td style="width: 50.0000%;">PLAN</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
      <p>Message:</p>
      <p> &nbsp; &nbsp; ${_questions.text}</p>
      ''',
      html: true,
    );

    if (await smtpman.send() == true) {
      debugPrint("Email has been sent!");
    } else {
      debugPrint("Failed to send, please check smtp credential.");
    }
  }
```